# python - how to sum the average of the amount per month per year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data records look like this

```
category    dt          userid  amt
1           4/14/2019       1   140
1           5/1/2019        1   500
2           5/5/2019        1   300 
3           5/19/2019       1   230
2           6/17/2019       1   200
4           6/18/2019       1   400
1           7/30/2019       1   400
1           8/17/2019       1   300
2           12/2/2019       1   200
2           12/23/2019      1   500
1           1/10/2019       2   470
1           2/25/2019       2   450
2           10/4/2019       2   350
```

Q1: How can I sum the average of the amount per month per year?

```
user    month1  month2  month3  month4  month5  month6  month7  month8  month9  month10 month11 month12 avg_all_month
1       0       0       0       140     343.33  300     400     300     0       0       0       350      305.55
2       470     450     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       350     0       0        423.33
```

Q2: How to count transaction per category

```
user   pro_cat1   pro_cat2  pro_cat3  pro_cat4    total_product
1      4          3         1         1           7
2      2          1         0         0           3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is same year you can use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) with mean per all months:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])

df2 = (df.pivot_table(index='userid', 
                    columns=df['dt'].dt.month, 
                    values='amt', 
                    aggfunc='mean',
                    fill_value=0)
       .reindex(range(1, 13), axis=1, fill_value=0)
       .add_prefix('month')
       .assign(avg_all_month = lambda x: df.groupby('userid')['amt'].mean())
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df2)
   userid  month1  month2  month3  month4      month5  month6  month7  month8  \
0       1       0       0       0     140  343.333333     300     400     300   
1       2     470     450       0       0    0.000000       0       0       0   

   month9  month10  month11  month12  avg_all_month  
0       0        0        0      350     317.000000  
1       0      350        0        0     423.333333
```

And then for second is used [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `sum`:

```
df3 = (pd.crosstab(df['userid'], 
                    df['category'])
        .add_prefix('pro_')
        .assign(total_product = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       )
print (df3)
   userid  pro_1  pro_2  pro_3  pro_4  total_product
0       1      4      4      1      1             10
1       2      2      1      0      0              3
```

Comment: if I want to join df, df2, df3, I can use merge, right?

Comment: @bee_me - I think yes, `df23 = df2.merge(df3, on='userid')` and then `df.merge(df23, on='userid', how='left')`

Comment: I have questions, df2 if I want change aggfunc='mean' to count each month have transcation or not? I mean use Yes/No instead of avg of mean, I put count but not working.  I create a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852711/python-how-to-count-transaction-per-month-per-year